# Is it possible to change the iOS Build Under review Over App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

Today I noticed that there is a bug in the app, an unwanted string displaying an id (used for testing purposes) in the build submitted to the app store, because I forgot to comment it out. The current review status is:

`July 03, 2014 00:17 | Apple | Waiting For Review`

Is it possible to change the iOS build under review?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Sure You Can Reject the app under review .Please do follow the steps given Below:

In iTunes connect, go into

- **'Manage Your Applications'** then click your application. Then
- **'View details'** and press
- **'Binary Details'** under 'Links'. You'll see the
- **'Reject this binary'** in the upper right corner.

Comment: it's now in the big blue banner at the top, in a blue link

Answer (score 1):

in iTunes Connect select your app, under Version press View Details, then under Links press Binary Details, finally on the top right there is a ***Reject this Binary*** Button.

Then you can submit a new version.

Answer (score 1):

The app status is "**Waiting for review**" and the only way to change the binary is to reject it yourself (*status will then be "developer rejected"*). Then you must go through the process again to upload the new binary.
 **This will consequently put you to the back of the queue.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is totally possible, I changed it because I had a missmatch between the version of the app described in the plist and the version my customer set on itunes connect.

0 problems. Hope it helps you.

Note you will have to reject the current one

Answer (score 0):

In iTunes connect, go into

1. Manage Your Applications' then click your application. Then
2. click App Store
3. you will see this "You can edit some information while your version is waiting for review. To submit a new build, you must remove this version from review."
4. click on  remove this version from review
5. Finally reject it for review